# Check class or class instance

Tags: objective-c

How to check if id is class definition or class instance? For example:

```
Class def =[NSString class];
NSString * inst= @"test";

[self check:def]; // should output "Class"
[self check:inst]; //should output "Instance"


-(void)check:(id)object
{
    if(objejct ... ){ // ???
        NSLog(@"Instance");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

then your check function needs to look like this

```
-(void)check:(id)object
{
    if(class_isMetaClass(object_getClass(object)))
    {
        NSLog(@"Class");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Instance");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, consider rewriting your `check:` method as a C function -- it doesn't make much sense to send a message to object A to see whether object B is class.